# Iterator with descending and ascending order does not work

Tags: java, iterator, deque

I'm trying to implement the following deque that implements an Iterable:

```
public class Dequeue<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    protected List<E> deque;

    public Dequeue() {
        this.deque = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void insertFirst( E elem ) {
        this.deque.add( 0, elem );
    }

    public void insertLast( E elem ) {
        this.deque.add( elem );
    }

    public E removeFirst() {
        return (this.deque.isEmpty()) ? null : this.deque.remove(0);
    }

    public E removeLast() {
        return (this.deque.isEmpty()) ? null : this.deque.remove( this.deque.size() - 1 );
    }

    public E examineFirst() {
        return this.deque.get(0);
    }

    public E examineLast() {
        return this.deque.get( this.deque.size() - 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new DequeIterator<>(false);
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator( boolean isDesc ) {
        return new DequeIterator<>(isDesc);
    }

    public class DequeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

        private int index;
        private boolean isDesc;

        public DequeIterator( boolean isdesc ) {
            this.index = isdesc ? deque.size() - 1 : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return isDesc ? index > 0 : index < deque.size();
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            this.index = (isDesc) ? index-- : index++;
            return (E) deque.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            deque.remove(index);
        }
    }

}
```

But if I try to test it with the following code, it goes into an infinite loop. What's happening? The compiler doesn't return any kind of error and I don't know if I'm doing the implementation of the Iterator class right.

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
Dequeue<Integer> deque = new Dequeue<>();
deque.insertLast( new Integer(1) );
deque.insertLast( new Integer(2) );

for( Integer i : deque ) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Because you never inserted anything into `result`?

Comment: You are supposed to iterate over `deque` not `result`

Comment: Also, `new Integer(1)` is unneeded. `1` will suffice.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! @NicolasFilotto but now I'm getting and infinite loop

Comment: @bradimus Well, this is embarrassing... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are actually `3` mistakes in your code:**

1. You don't iterate over `deque` but over the useless list `result`
2. You don't affect the value of the member variable `isDesc` in the constructor of the class `DequeIterator`.
3. You don't manage properly the index in the method `DequeIterator#next()`, you affect the value of the post incrementation/decrementation which will end up with the same index so to an infinite loop, use directly the result of the post incrementation/decrementation as index.

**Here is the code fixed:**

```
Dequeue<Integer> deque = new Dequeue<>();
deque.insertLast(1);
deque.insertLast(2);

for( Integer i : deque ) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**And the class `Dequeue.DequeIterator`**

```
public class DequeIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    ...
    private boolean isDesc;

    public DequeIterator( boolean isdesc ) {
        ...
        this.isDesc = isdesc;
    }

   ...

    @Override
    public E next() {
        return (E) deque.get(isDesc ? index-- : index++);
    }

    ...
}
```